# Bind timeout to specific HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons. When clicking on one of the buttons, I want to add a small checkmark after the button text and remove it after 1 second with a timeout.

This works fine as long as I don't click 2 or more buttons within the 1 second time frame.

To see the issue, just click 2 or 3 buttons within 1 second. The checkmark will only be removed on the last clicked button.

How can I solve this issue? I would think the timeout could be bound to the clicked element but I don't know how to achieve that.

```js
// Get all .copy-clip buttons
let copyEls = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-clip');
let timeoutHandle;

// For each button
copyEls.forEach(el => {

  // Register click event listener
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // Reset the inner HTML to avoid multiple copy checkmarks
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy';

    // Reset timeout
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    // Add copy checkmark in button inner HTML
    e.target.innerHTML += '<span class="copy-check"> &#x2713;</span>';

    // Remove copy checkmark after 1 sec
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy'
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's only *one* `timeoutHandle`.  So as soon as a second value is assigned to it, the previous value is lost.  Instead, create a new one in each iteration of the loop.  For example:

```js
// Copy to clipboard
let copyEls = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-clip');

// For each copy button
copyEls.forEach(el => {

  let timeoutHandle; // <-- here

  // Register click event listener
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // Reset the inner HTML to avoid multiple copy checkmarks
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy';

    // Reset timeout
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    // Add copy checkmark in button inner HTML
    e.target.innerHTML += '<span class="copy-check"> &#x2713;</span>';

    // Remove copy checkmark after 1 sec
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy'
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was even easier that I thought and I didn't spot the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, delegated and does not add/remove DOM elements

Storing the timeout handle in the button

```js
document.getElementById('buttonContainer').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button.copy-clip");
  if (!tgt) return;
  clearTimeout(tgt.dataset.tm);
  const check = tgt.querySelector('.copy-check');
  check.hidden = false;
  tgt.dataset.tm = setTimeout(() => check.hidden = true, 1000);
})
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button class="copy-clip">Copy <span class="copy-check" hidden> &#x2713;</span></button><br>
  <button class="copy-clip">Copy <span class="copy-check" hidden> &#x2713;</span></button><br>
  <button class="copy-clip">Copy <span class="copy-check" hidden> &#x2713;</span></button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. That said the timeout is not *reset* in case you click multiple times on the same button.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Oops. It is now

Comment: Also the click event is bound to the container and not the buttons themselves. In my case, the buttons are not layout that way, all in a common container so this would require modifications.

Comment: You can use the closest common static container you want. The `e.target.closest("button.copy-clip");` will handle click ONLY on a copy-clip button or its content

Comment: Sure I could use another container. Still, clicking anywhere on that container *does* trigger the click event (not doing anything with the buttons, but it's still reacting to the click). Not sure this is what you aimed for. Would you still do it this way?

Comment: Always depends on the situation. `const tgt = e.target.closest("button.copy-clip"); if (!tgt) return;` will ignore all clicks not on the buttons in question.

Comment: Is it better in terms of performance? Or why would you do it this way rather than listening for the click event on each button?

Comment: If the elements to click on are all in a container AND/OR if dynamically added, then I will ALWAYS delegate.
If they are all over the place then possibly not. I have never had the second situation

Answer (score 1):

Move `let timeoutHandle;` into the loop

```js
// Copy to clipboard
let copyEls = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-clip');


// For each copy button
copyEls.forEach(el => {

  let timeoutHandle;

  // Register click event listener
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // Reset the inner HTML to avoid multiple copy checkmarks
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy';

    // Reset timeout
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    // Add copy checkmark in button inner HTML
    e.target.innerHTML += '<span class="copy-check"> &#x2713;</span>';

    // Remove copy checkmark after 1 sec
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Copy'
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
<button class="copy-clip">Copy</button><br>
```

Comment: I have accepted the other answer because it contains an explanation as to *why* the variable should be moved inside the loop.